# Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, gradlew

I delete .gradle folder in drive C then don't give apk.
while "gradlew assembleRelease" give me this error

While with this command "npx react-native run android", the object maker gives the debug version

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\shahrelaptop.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\642ab371edaad2abbcb9b95c928eb744\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

I clear cashe clean node and npm

but dont work